# Dynamic background image

Tags: image

I'm super new to Craft and was wondering if someone could help.

I'm trying to set up a hero banner. So there will be a full-width image, on top of this will be the heading text and a CTA button.

I'd like the background to be editable by the user so have set up a field for this called 'hero image'. This is how it looks now but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('{{heroImage}}');">
    <div id="home">
        <div class="hero-overlay">
            <header id="site-header">  
                <div class="main-message">  
                    <div class="container">
                        <p class="description-image">
                            {{ entry.description }}
                        </p>

                        <a class="btn btn-cta-primary btn-cta-blue" href="{{entry.buttonUrl}}" role="button">{{ entry.buttonText }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm so confused!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It didn't seem to paste in my code?
<div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('{{heroImage}}');">
    <div id="home">
      <div class="hero-overlay">
        <header id="site-header">  
          <div class="main-message">  
            <div class="container">
              <p class="description-image">
                {{entry.description}}
              </p>
              <a class="btn btn-cta-primary btn-cta-blue" href="{{entry.buttonUrl}}" role="button">{{entry.buttonText}}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues with your code. (1) Unless you set `heroImage` as a variable somewhere, then you need to change `heroImage` to `entry.heroImage`. (2) But, an asset field returns an assetModel, not the actual image. To access the image, you need to use `.first()` to select the first asset in the assetModel. (3) Then you need to access the URL on that image, by using `url`.

This code should work:

```
{% set heroImage = entry.heroImage.first() %}

<div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('{{ heroImage.url() }}');">
    <div id="home">
        <div class="hero-overlay">
            <header id="site-header">
                <div class="main-message">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p class="description-image"> {{ entry.description }}</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-cta-primary btn-cta-blue" href="{{ entry.buttonUrl }}" role="button">{{ entry.buttonText }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!

I just tried it and it says 

"Internal Server Error
The block 'content' has already been defined line 2."

Comment: @Chris as the code I posted nowhere references a `content` block, that probably has to do with something else in that template.